# Write only the first X outputs in foreach loop to file (inside associative array)?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

I have an associative array that is pulling data into a review table template.

This is a "secondary table" that is at the bottom of the page, where only X items will fit. I'm trying to write only the first X items to a file.

Checkboxes are generating the $selections with selection[].

```
$result = array();
foreach( array_rand($selections, count($selections)) as $k ) {
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/bottomfeature.php";
}
```

Note that there are other files being utilized by this loop, not just bottomfeature.php.

Inside of bottomfeature.php, I assemble the feature title for example (and other elements, but just for example:

```
$featuretitle =  $result[] = $selections[$k];

$featurearray = array(
"<tr>",
"<td>$featuretitle</td>",
"</tr>"
);
$feature = implode("\n",$featurearray);

$fp = fopen("bottomfeature.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp, $feature);
fclose($fp);
```

There's only enough for 4 outputs at the bottom of this page. How could I stop the execution at the 4th?

Also, what about only writing the first output? I tried using "w" in fopen.

```
$fp = fopen("bottomfeature.txt", "w");
```

But it only writes the last item of the loop instead of the first.

Thanks for the help.

Updated with html checkboxes

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

$result = array();
foreach( array_rand($selections, count($selections)) as $k ) {
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/bottomfeature.php";
}

}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="Brand1">Brand1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="Brand2">Brand2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="Brand3">Brand3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="Brand4">Brand4</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Setup" />
</form>
```

Comment: @mickmackusa -- $featurearray is in an associative array pulled in via "bottomfeature.php". A unique value is added every time a selection is made via HTML checkboxes. I tried using break;, but get the error "Cannot break/continue 1 level" because (from my research) the code if inside an if-statement.

Comment: I updated the OP with the way the code is being run. On the submission, each checkbox is pulled into the loop, and the data is used there. If you execute this, the fopen will write (being you check all 4 boxes), 4 outputs consecutively to the file. My question is -- how can I make it only write the first one, or, only the first 3?

Comment: The second snippet is being run inside of bottomfeature.php which is insane of the loop.... the data is in the loop... what you're suggesting would prevent the other functions of the loop from triggering properly, but, I could just make a separate loop for bottomfeature.php with $selections that may do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a counter that starts from 0 in your foreach loop by merely using the indexes -- this spares you having to manually increment a counter.

The include can reference the counter and the limit in its condition block to determine if the file should be updated. The other processes can run on all submitted values.

Demo:  https://3v4l.org/I6bnC

```
$limit = 4;
$selections = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
shuffle($selections);
foreach ($selections as $i => $selection) {
    echo "before include $selection\n";
    // start include code...
        if ($i < $limit) {
            echo "**display limited $selection**\n";
        }
    // end include code
    echo "after include $selection\n";
    echo "---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
before include d
**display limited d**
after include d
---
before include b
**display limited b**
after include b
---
before include a
**display limited a**
after include a
---
before include c
**display limited c**
after include c
---
before include e
after include e
---
```

---

I'll transfer my other comments to my answer so that I csn delete them...

This doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
$featurearray = array(
"<tr>",
"<td>$featuretitle</td>",
"</tr>"
);
$feature = implode("\n",$featurearray);
```

Because `$featurearray` is declared as a single element array on each iteration (it keeps getting overwritten), the better data type to use is `string` instead of `array`. Because there is only one element, the `\n` glue is never used.

I do not recommend making iterated modifications to your file.  A better / more efficient process would be to prepare the new data, then write it to the file after the loop is finished.  I recommend a redesign of your scripts.

Comment: Yea, I figured it out thanks to the help of a friend... It was way easier than I thought. $counter = 1; //outside of loop $countme = ($counter++); ///// if ( $countme == 1 ) { do this } else {} . and multiple if ( $counterme<5 ) { do this } else {}. I'm marking your answer as correct even though the solution was even slightly simpler than this.